# existence reflexive subcategory of topos

Tags: ct.category-theory, topos-theory

$M$ is a monoid and $sets^{M}$ the topos of m-sets associated with $C$ a full subcategory of $sets^{M}$, it is possible to construct a reflexive subcategory of $sets^{M}$ from $C$ ? (different to $sets^{M}$ ) or what conditions are needed such that  exists a smallest reflective (replete, full) subcategory containing $C$(like a Grothendieck topos).

Comment: Well, $Set^M$ is a reflexive subcategory of itself, so you have an answer. Perhaps a better question is whether there is a smallest reflective full subcategory of $Set^C$ ($C$ a small category) containing a given class of objects. I'm not quite sure, but at least under the weak Vopenka principle, the closure of the class under small limits would be the smallest reflexive subcategory. See Adamek-Rosicky, Locally Presentable and Accessible Categories, section 6.D.

Comment: To repeat myself, I think a much more fruitful question is whether there exists a *smallest* reflective (replete, full) subcategory containing a given class $K$ of objects in a given category (like a Grothendieck topos) $C$. The smallest such, when it exists, is called the *reflexive hull* of $K$. This is not an area of category theory I've studied before now, but it's apparently been studied a lot. This paper looks very useful, with lots of references, and should help get you started: http://www.math.mcgill.ca/barr/papers/biref.pdf.